# Vertical Progress Bar on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, adapter

I want to implement progress bar on list view for data that am getting from Mysql server here is my code any new suggestion are welcome for an example change your layout or anything which will make implementation easy as am neophyte

```
public class teststatusActivity extends BaseActivity {

String myJSON = "" ;
private static final String TAG_RESULTS = "result";
private static final String TAG_TICKET = "ticket_id";
private static final String TAG_Status = "ticket_status";
private static final String TAG_Status1 = "ticket_status1";
private static final String TAG_Status2 = "ticket_status2";
private static final String TAG_Status3 = "ticket_status3";



private static final String TAG_I = "";

public static final String DATA_URL = "http://103.3.62.23/complain_dashboard/api/getTicketStatus.php?ticket_id=";

public String ticketID;




JSONArray peoples = null;


ListView list;


ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> usersList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_teststatus);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);



    usersList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    getData();


}

protected void showList() {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
        JSONObject pe = jsonObj.getJSONObject(TAG_RESULTS);


        String id = pe.getString("ticket_id");
        String status = pe.getString("ticket_status");
        String stat = null;
        String stat1 = null;
        String stat2 = null;
        String stat3 = null;



        if (pe.get("ticket_status").equals("0")) {
            stat = "Feedback Sent To Team";
        }
         if (pe.get("ticket_status").equals("1")) {
            stat1 = "Technical Team is Working on it";
        }

         if (pe.get("ticket_status").equals("2")) {
            stat2 = "Your Report is About To Resolve";
        }
        if (pe.get("ticket_status").equals("3")) {
            stat3 = "Resolved";
        }


        HashMap<String, String> users = new HashMap<String, String>();

        users.put( TAG_TICKET , id  );
        users.put(TAG_Status,  stat );
       users.put(TAG_Status1,  stat1 );
       users.put(TAG_Status2,  stat2);
       users.put(TAG_Status3,  stat3);



        usersList.add(users);


        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                teststatusActivity.this, usersList, R.layout.list_item,
                new String[]{TAG_TICKET, TAG_Status,TAG_Status1, TAG_Status2, TAG_Status3 },
                new int[]{R.id.feed, R.id.feedS, R.id.feedwork, R.id.abouttoresolve, R.id.resolved}
        );

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void getData() {



   class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
       SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("tcktid", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
       final String ticket =sharedPref.getString("tid", null);

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());


            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(DATA_URL + ticket);

            // Depends on your web service
            httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");


            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = null;
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                // json is UTF-8 by default
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (inputStream != null) inputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception squish) {
                }
            }
            return result;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            myJSON = result;
            showList();
        }
    }

    GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
            g.execute();


        }


    } ;
```

Comment: You need to explain your question a bit more. What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: thanks for your reply wanna acheive vertical progress bar for every status update in list view